# django save(commit = False) vs setting initial value

Tags: ajax, django, form-submit, commit

I have a django project and in one of the pages I have a form where I set `commit=False` on the `form.save` so I can add a value for a foreign key.

When I do so, the rest of the values in the form don't save.

Basically I am getting two errors depending on how I save the form.

The first is when I use `save.(commit=False)`

code:

```
form = RecipeForm()
form = form.save(commit=False)
form.original_cookbook = request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]
form.save()
```

error:

```
IntegrityError at /cookbook/createrecipe/

(1048, "Column 'ingredients' cannot be null")

Request Method:     POST
```

But I know that my ingredients field is not null.

The second error is when I don't use commit and instead set an initial value.

code:

```
form = RecipeForm(initial = {'original_cookbook' : request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})
form.save()
```

error:

```
IntegrityError at /cookbook/createrecipe/

(1048, "Column 'original_cookbook_id' cannot be null")

Request Method:     POST
```

Any idea why neither of these methods seem to work? Just so you know I am trying to submit a form via AJAX...

Comment: "but i know that my ingredients field is not null" How?

Comment: well perhaps that is not fully accurate but what I meant is that I entered a value for ingredients in the form. is there a way to check this?

Comment: Print the value that the model attribute has to stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original form is unbound, which is why when you try to save it, it doesn't validate since the fields are empty.

You should use:

```
form = RecipieForm(request.POST)
```

This would populate the form from the values filled in, and then you can proceed as normal.